# Force usage in cellular data instead of wifi

Tags: ios, swift, wifi, reachability, cellular-network

In my app I am detecting if there is an internet connection and through what connection (wifi or cellular).

I want to know if there is an option to force the app using the cellular data in case that I am connected to wifi but for some reason or malfunction there is no internet.

Comment: The OS manages the network connection, I think apart from installing trust certificates or VPN profiles you dont have any other control over it

Comment: @Scriptable i think you right.
I did some experiment and connected my phone to a router with no internet connection and it didn't moved to the cellular data.

Comment: it will eventually, mine does that sometimes but its managed by the os, you can't control it

Comment: @Scriptable thanks for the info !

Comment: This situation would affect the whole device and any app the user is trying to use. This really should not be managed at the app level. Let the OS or the user deal with it.

Comment: @ironRoei I think i want to reach the same result, My target is to allow the app to function normally, but force it to use Cellular Data on a specific API. Can you please advice if you did find a solution. ?